# scipy: Interpolating trajectory

Tags: python, interpolation, spline

I have a trajectory formed by a sequence of *(x,y)* pairs. I would like to interpolate points on this trajectory using splines.

How do I do this? Using `scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline` doesn't work because neither *x* nor *y* are monotonic. I could introduce a parametrization (e.g. length *d* along the trajectory), but then I have two dependent variables *x(d)* and *y(d)*.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

error = 0.1
x0 = 1
y0 = 1
r0 = 0.5

alpha = np.linspace(0, 2*math.pi, 40, endpoint=False)
r = r0 + error * np.random.random(len(alpha))
x = x0 + r * np.cos(alpha)
y = x0 + r * np.sin(alpha)
plt.scatter(x, y, color='blue', label='given')

# For this special case, the following code produces the
# desired results. However, I need something that depends
# only on x and y:
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
alpha_i = np.linspace(alpha[0], alpha[-1], 100)
r_i = interp1d(alpha, r, kind=3)(alpha_i)
x_i = x0 + r_i * np.cos(alpha_i)
y_i = x0 + r_i * np.sin(alpha_i)
plt.plot(x_i, y_i, color='green', label='desired')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: example data]

Comment: @alinsoar: the (x,y) data in the example doesn't do?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using splprep you can interpolate over curves of any geometry.

```
from scipy import interpolate
tck,u=interpolate.splprep([x,y],s=0.0)
x_i,y_i= interpolate.splev(np.linspace(0,1,100),tck)
```

Which produces a plot like the one given, but only using the x and y points and not the alpha and r paramters.
[image: Same as yours only using x and y points.]

Sorry about my original answer, I misread the question.

Comment: Is there a way to control the thickness of the connections?